# See the total runtime a IMDb My Movies list has

Tags: imdb

I have a My Movies list on IMDb.com and I would like to see how much runtime all the movies and/or TV series in this list sum in total.

For example: *Movie A* has a 90 minute runtime, *Movie B* has a 120 minute runtime, *Series C* has 2 episodes of 30 minutes each. The sum would be 270 minutes or 4 hours, 30 minutes. This is what I am searching for—the total.

Is there a way to get this information from the website, that I am unaware of?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, you would have hacked their site and put there such script ;). But, what you can do... is  to write some program/addon for your browser. I think maybe GreaseMonkey could do something like that. Try to search **greasemonkey firefox** and go this way. Or hire some programmer who can write asuch monitoring script for Chrome or Firefox. basically the addon should save the entering time and leavving time for your list URL and save it. HTen you can do everything what you want with these results. So, finding a pregrammer who can write this addon is the best thing you can do in my opinion. That's my advice for you ;)

Comment: im not sure if you understood my question correctly. i dont want to see how long i have been surfing on that site. i want to sum the duration of each movie/series together to get the complete time. for example: movie 1 has a duration of 90min and movie 2 a duration of 120 -> 210min would be the number i wanted to search for.

but thank you for your effort.

Comment: OK, so you need to scrape the site (with a custom made script that could be written in every language e.g. PHP, Python etc.) and find the divs or other elements you are interested in e.g. the name of the movie and the duration. E.g. if you look at http://www.imdb.com/list/-7fJjrdRgpA/ and view the source code, you will see that there is a div with a class "list_item" so you need to get all these divs. Then, inside this list_item div, you are looking for the div called "b" which contain an a href tag with the name. So you need to grab the text within this tag.

Comment: The second thing you need is the duration of this movie and this info is a little tricky. You have to get the item_description div and grab the content inside this div and use some regex to find and grab the integer value before the "mins.)" string.

Comment: These information you can store in a database and process however you like. But writing actual script is a little complicated for a beginner. Try to find someone, who can write it for you. It will cost from 50 to 100 bucks if you find someone who is good in building sitescrappers and is able to write it in 1-2 hours.

Comment: Check this link for an example: http://www.sunilb.com/php/writing-website-scrapers-in-php . Hope my comments help ;)

Comment: since this comments pretty much cover the whole thing i will mark your first answer as correct to give credit to your comments. thank you for your in-depth guide

Answer (score 0):

You can simply export the respective list from IMDb as a .csv file and open it with Excel. There you will have a `Runtime(mins)` column with the length in minutes for every movie and than you can simply make Excel calculate the sum for you.